# Python Multiprocessing Run Until Function Returns False

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
points = Set of points i.e.: set((x1,y1),(x2,y2), etc)
polygon = List of points i.e.: [(x1,y1),(x2,y2), etc]
pointInsidePolygon((point, polygon)) returns True if the point is inside the polygon
```

Here is my single thread code:

```
for point in points:
    if pointInsidePolygon((point, polygon)):
        return False
return True
```

Basically I have a huge list of points and I want to check if any point is inside the polygon. If there is a point inside the polygon, I don't need to keep checking if others are.

I am trying to do this with multiple threads. Ideally if one thread gets a `True` for `pointInsidePolygon`, the other threads should stop but even if they don't, it might still be faster.

Here is what I have:

```
pointsInside = multiprocessing.Pool().map(pointInsidePolygon, [(point, polygon) for point in points)
if not numpy.all(pointsInside):
    return False
return True
```

I get the following error: `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`

I can't change anything on the OS as this needs to work on similar computer's without modification. How can I change this to not run into the error? I am just trying to make this faster. `pointInsidePolygon` can't be altered. Thanks.

Comment: You need to post more of your code, as there is not a single `open` statement in your code. Also, don't expect it to speed up. Python multiprocessing does not speed up code, thanks to the GIL.

Comment: A way of speeding up your code would be to use NumPy to do the calculation of thousands of rows at the same time, but that would require you to rewrite `pointInsidePolygon`.

Comment: @NilsWerner There are no `open` statements in my code.... Pool.map() is causing the error, not me opening a file.

Comment: You might want to use a smaller number of processes to operate on groups of points.

Comment: Then there is some other part of the code opening a file.